# Spring boot @Autowired Annotation not working when deploying on Tomcat

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7, vaadin-spring-boot

@Autowired gives null when deploying my spring boot app packaged as war on tomcat however it works fine when using the embedded tomcat of spring boot.
Any help please ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    flexedge-css
    war
    flexedge-css
    Consular Services Scheduler
    
        com.flexedge.css
        flexedge-css-bom
        0.2.0
    
    
        UTF-8
        UTF-8
        1.8
    
    
        
            vaadin-addons
            http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons
            
                true

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.tapio</groupId>
        <artifactId>googlemaps</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.flexedge.css</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexedge-css-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you follow all the steps described in the official doc? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Answer (score 0):

the below pom.xml file work fine in my application and when deployed to standalone Tomcat also.Do check if you have made scope as provided for embedded server in your pom.xml file.

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringBootExamples</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <java.version>1.7</java.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.38</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                      <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.11.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nativelibs4java/bridj -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.nativelibs4java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bridj</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Apache FOP -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Apache PDFBox -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.23</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>19.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
                    <name>Java.net repository</name>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </project>
```

Can you please paste your pom.xml file.

Comment: pdfbox is at 2.0.4 now. (Not relevant to the answer, but may be relevant for you)

Comment: Subhasish Sahu, I added my pom.xml in the post above.

Comment: @Syrine - Can you please paste the whole of your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

@Syrine

Since i dont have your child project , i have combined both the pom.xml file content into one and it ran fine in my local.Please compare it with your pom.xml file.

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>com.subu</groupId>
                <artifactId>SpringBootExamples</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>war</packaging>
                <parent>
                    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                </parent>
                <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
                </properties>
                 <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin.tapio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>googlemaps</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.38</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                       <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>4.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- <modules>
                    <module>flexedge-css</module>
                    <module>flexedge-css-ejb</module>
                    <module>flexedge-cssadmin</module>
                </modules> -->
                <dependencyManagement>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                            <version>7.7.3</version>
                            <type>pom</type>
                            <scope>import</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </dependencyManagement>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </project>
```